# Defining Multiple Dictionaries Within a Loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

What I'm looking to do is to define three very similar dictionaries with only subtle differences. If you recognize this it is one of the problems from the Codeacademy course on Python, and I'm looking to do it a little more elegantly. Anyways, here's what I have:

```
import string
for name in ["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]:
    name = {"name": string.capitalize(name), "homework": [], "quizzes": [], "tests": []}
```

This isn't working. What I want is three dictionaries, which have the names "lloyd" "alice" and "tyler" and with keys of their names (but capitalized), "homework", "quizzes", and "tests"

To clarify, the output I want is equivalent to this:

```
lloyd = {"name": "Lloyd", "homework": [], "quizzes": [], "tests": []}
alice = {"name": "Alice", "homework": [], "quizzes": [], "tests": []}
tyler = {"name": "Tyler", "homework": [], "quizzes": [], "tests": []}
```

Comment: Depending on your needs/preference, you could also create a new class to represent students, with attributes "name", "homework", etc. and methods/functions for working with that information. But dictionaries are wonderful, so no discontent there as long as your students have unique names :)

Comment: *Why* are you importing `string`? The functions in that module were mostly deprecated in *python 1.6* or something like that. You should use the methods of the string objects instead.

Answer (score 7):

I think instead of creating a variable for each name you can create a dict of names with each name pointing to a dictionary.

```
>>> names=["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]
>>> keys=["homework", "quizzes", "tests"]
>>> dic={ name.capitalize():{ key:[] for key in keys} for name in names}
>>> dic
{'Tyler': {'quizzes': [], 'tests': [], 'homework': []}, 
 'Lloyd': {'quizzes': [], 'tests': [], 'homework': []},
 'Alice': {'quizzes': [], 'tests': [], 'homework': []}}
```

Now to access `Tyler` simply use:

```
>>> dic['Tyler']
{'quizzes': [], 'tests': [], 'homework': []}
```

Answer (score 2):

In python you *cannot* create *local* variables at runtime. You have to explicitly assign a value to them.

Something like this:

```
locals()['lloyd'] = {...}
locals()['alice'] = {...}
locals()['tyler'] = {...}
```

does **not** create the *local* variables `lloyd`, `alice` and `tyler`:

```
>>> def some_function():
...     locals()['lloyd'] = {}
...     print lloyd
... 
>>> some_function()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in some_function
NameError: global name 'lloyd' is not defined
```

Quoting from the documentation for [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

> **Note** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; **changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter**.

What you *can* do is to create **global** variables at runtime, using the dictionary returned by [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals).
Although I don't see why you should do something like that.

However you could use the `copy` module to avoid repeating the `dict` definition:

```
import copy
base_dict = {"homework": [], "quizzes": [], "tests": []}
lloyd = copy.deepcopy(base_dict)
alice = copy.deepcopy(base_dict)
tyler = copy.deepcopy(base_dict)
for the_dict, name in ((lloyd, "lloyd"), (alice, "alice"), (tyler, "tyler")):
    the_dict["name"] = name.capitalize()
```

Or without the loop:

```
import copy
base_dict = {"homework": [], "quizzes": [], "tests": []}
lloyd = copy.deepcopy(base_dict)
alice = copy.deepcopy(base_dict)
tyler = copy.deepcopy(base_dict)
lloyd["name"], alice["name"], tyler["name"] = "lloyd", "alice", "tyler"
```

Depending on what you want to do using a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) could be a good idea:

```
from collections import defaultdict
lloyd = defaultdict(list)
alice = defaultdict(list)
tyler = defaultdict(list)
lloyd["name"], alice["name"], tyler["name"] = "lloyd", "alice", "tyler"
```

The `defaultdict`, instead of raises a `KeyError` when the key is not found, it creates a default value(in this case an empty `list`) and sets that value as the value of the key, hence you don't need to specify `"tests": []`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, leaving one `dict` at the end named `name` with the last name in the list of names as the value under `'name'`. Maybe you mean to add all the `name` dicts to a list?

```
all_dicts = []

for name in names:
   name = {yadda yadda}
   all_dicts.append(name)
```

Or even make a new dict and then set the key of that new dict to the names pulled from the list.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not very clear

If you want dictionaries with keys the names in `["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]`, then this is doing it

```
import string
dictionaries = {}  # dicts
for name in ["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]:
    dictionaries[string.capitalize(name)]={"homework": [], 
        "quizzes": [], "tests": []}
```

Result is

```
>>> dictionaries
{'Tyler': {'quizzes': [], 'tests': [], 'homework': []}, 
 'Lloyd': {'quizzes': [], 'tests': [], 'homework': []}, 
 'Alice': {'quizzes': [], 'tests': [], 'homework': []}}
```

Comment: there's no need of importing `string`, you can simply use `name.capitalize()`.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: this is hacky AF. It works, but if I saw this in my codebase, I would frown.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name.capitalize()
        self.quizzes=[]
        self.tests=[]
        self.homework=[]
#this
Jane =Student('jane')
JanesDict = Jane.__dict__
#or
JimsDict = Student('jim').__dict__
```

pretty much creates a dictionary for a new student with one line.